# SharePoint 2013 app "No such host is known"

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-addin

Added an app on SharePoint development server. It installed successful but when run it gives an error

> DNS Lookup failed. System.Net.Sockets.SocketException No such host is known

How to resolve it?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. My app domain is set up and the wildcard CNAME is in the DNS server. Any ideas what the issue might be?

Answer (score 0):

What steps did you follow to set up your app domain? Part of that procedure should have been configuring a separate domain for apps, so if your SharePoint box is:

```
team.mycompany.com
```

Perhaps the app domain would be something like:

```
mycompanyapps.com
```

Then, in DNS, you would need a wildcard record so that all of the following would resolve to the ip address of the SharePoint box:

```
abc.mycompanyapps.com

xyz.mycompanyapps.com

anyRandomStringOfCharacters.mycompanyapps.com
```

And, if SP is running on SSL, then the app domain should be configured for SSL as well.